# OpenERP New column not showing up in DB Table

Tags: database, postgresql, openerp-8

I am trying to access the field manufacturer_pref from the product.product table from the purchase order report.

This is the module that created the field :

```
class product_product(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'product.product'
_columns = {
    'manufacturer' : fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Manufacturer'),
    'manufacturer_pname' : fields.char('Manufacturer Product Name', size=64),
    'manufacturer_pref' : fields.char('Manufacturer Product Code', size=64),
    'attribute_ids': fields.one2many('product.manufacturer.attribute', 'product_id', 'Attributes'),
}
```

I went in the purchase module, edited purchase.py and added this under _columns = {

```
'manufacturer_pref': fields.related('order_line','manufacturer_pref', type='char', relation='product.product', string='Manufacturer'),
```

saved, did a

```
./openerp-server -db My_DB -u=all
```

and when I get back in pgAdminIII, when I look in purchase_order_line table, the column is not showing up.

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: Maybe a missing commit when the columns are added?

Comment: Could you explain your comment, I am not getting it.

Comment: Lets see it that way.
In my table purchase order line, I would like to add a column for both, the manufacturer name (manufacturer_pname) and manufacturer code(manufacturer_pref). those 2 are fields of product wich are located in product.product table.
in the table purchase.order.line, I have the field product_id which is related to my product id in product.product table
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('purchase_ok','=',True)], change_default=True),
so, I would I get those 2 fields from that product.product table into purchase.order.line table ?

Comment: I have change the line to: 
'manufacturer_pref': fields.many2one('product.product','manufacturer_pref'),

The column was created but, it still does not get the value from the product.product table field manufacturer_pref